# Odoo 10 Error - I need to send one2many values to another model has the same one2many field

Tags: odoo-10

I am receiving an Odoo 10 error.

I need to send one2many values to another model that has the same one2many field.

When I send the one2many field using my workflow, I had this error expected singleton, (1,4,6).

How can I solve this problem?

```
file_upload_material = fields.One2many('file.decision','param_two')

@api.multi
def confirm(self):
    file = self.file_upload_material.file
    name = self.file_upload_material.name
    if self.name:
        media_and_media = {
            'name': self.name,
            'instructions': self.instructions,
            'task_id': self.task_id.id,
            'descriptions': self.descriptions,
            'date_from_exec': self.date_from_exec,
            'date_to_exec': self.date_to_exec,
            'date_from': self.date_from,
            'task_name': self.task_name,
            'file_upload_material': [(0, 0, {
                'name': name,
                'file': file
            })],

        }
        self.env['my.task.log'].create(media_and_media)
        self.state = 'unread'


        class LogMydecision(models.Model):
             _name = "my.task.log"
       file_upload_material = fields.One2many('file.decision','param_one')


       class FileUpload(models.Model):

            _name = 'file.decision'

            name = fields.Char('File Name')
            file = fields.Binary('Upload File')
            param_one = fields.Many2one('my.task.log)
            param_two = fields.Many2one('task.log)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error seems related to the value of the field file_upload_material that contains a recordset and you are using it as like if there contains only one record(like m2o), specifically on this lines:

```
file = self.file_upload_material.file
name = self.file_upload_material.name
```

Your issue could be solved like this:

```
media_and_media = {
    'name': self.name,
    'instructions': self.instructions,
    'task_id': self.task_id.id,
    'descriptions': self.descriptions,
    'date_from_exec': self.date_from_exec,
    'date_to_exec': self.date_to_exec,
    'date_from': self.date_from,
    'task_name': self.task_name,
    'file_upload_material': [(0, 0, {
        'name': fum.name,
        'file': fum.file
    }) for fum in self.file_upload_material],
}
```

Also seems that you are duplicating the value of the file.decision records by copying at the confirm method, you could change the field to a m2m and reuse it or also you could write the relation between the existing record with (4, id) or (6,0,[ids]) instead of using (0,0,{vals}), like this:

```
media_and_media = {
    'name': self.name,
    'instructions': self.instructions,
    'task_id': self.task_id.id,
    'descriptions': self.descriptions,
    'date_from_exec': self.date_from_exec,
    'date_to_exec': self.date_to_exec,
    'date_from': self.date_from,
    'task_name': self.task_name,
    'file_upload_material': [(6, 0, self.file_upload_material.ids)],
}
```

That prevent the record duplication. Also I will recommends you to switch to m2m fields for `file_upload_material` relations

Comment: hello thanks, but you suggest is't work the same error still appear